# Make a preprocessor error at a specific line

Tags: c++, c, c-preprocessor

I'm making a cross-platform program for Windows, Unix and Mac. To be able to use things that are specific for each OS, I use a `#define`, for example when I'm compiling for Windows, I use `#define WINDOWS`. To make sure not to define an OS that doesn't exist, or at least that my program doesn't support, I use this:

```
#ifndef WINDOWS
#ifndef UNIX
#ifndef MAC
#error "OS must be WINDOWS, UNIX or MAC"
#endif
#endif
#endif
```

When I define an invalid OS, is gives me an error as it should, but it puts the red rectangle that means error in front of the `#error` line. I would like to put it in front of the line where I defined the OS. For example, if I'm supposed to define the OS on line 11, I would like it to send me to line 11. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How, you define OS on line 11 ? With just (for example) #define WINDOWS ? If

Comment: @vadikrobot I define OS on line 11 means that line 11 in my program contains for example `#define WINDOWS`.

Comment: And if this line is absent, you would like to see an error on this line ?

Comment: @vadikrobot The program isn't supposed to be shorter than that number of lines. If that line contains something else, I would like it to put the error there anyway, since it's not supposed to contain anything else.

Comment: Your logic i backward, Donald Duck.    Your code is testing if the macro is NOT defined, so the `#error` will never activate if it is.

Comment: @Peter That's exactly what I want. If the macro `WINDOWS`, `UNIX` or `MAC` is defined, it's OK since my program is for one of these. If none is defined, there is a problem, so that's when I want there to be an error.

Comment: `#define PI 3.14159265` Here, I have defined an OS. `#define NDEBUG` here's another one. `#define BIG_ENDIAN 0x1234` and another one.

Comment: You're missing the point.   If they are NOT defined, the typical use case is that there is NO place where they have been defined.   It is not possible to report where something was defined if it is not defined.

Comment: @DonaldDuck If I understand you want, show an error on line 11, if there is now defined macros.

Comment: @Peter That specific line is the line where the OS should be defined (the previous line contains a comment explaining that) and since it's my code, I know that that's where the OS should be defined. The main reason why I want to do this is in case I make a typing mistake which I don't notice (for example write `WINDDOWS` instead of `WINDOWS`). That would do so that I don't have to go around looking for the error in my whole code.

Comment: @DonaldDuck Try this. #ifndef WINDOWS
#ifndef UNIX
#ifndef MAC
#line 11
#error "OS must be WINDOWS, UNIX or MAC"
#endif
#endif
#endif

Comment: @vadikrobot Thanks, that worked to add `#line 11` before the `#error` (even though everything shouldn't be on the same line). You can post that as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you would like to show an error on specific line if there is no defined macros on your code, try to use **#line**

```
1 #ifndef UNIX
2 #ifndef MAC
3 #line 11 
4 #error "OS must be WINDOWS, UNIX or MAC" 
5 #endif 
6 #endif 
7 #endif 
8    
9  int main ()
10 {
11   // here will be error from line 4
12 }
```

Answer (score 2):

The preprocessor is quite simple. The only option you have here is including the line number in the error message. Because if you `#define` that number elsewhere, how are you sure that this `#define` was even processed, as this scenario misses other definitions (the OS you're checking for). Additionally, there's no way you can define all three macros on the same line number, unless you have separate headers for each of these things, which seems like a very fragile system. Bottom line is you can't figure out where something should be defined if it was never defined in the first place.

If this is pure C++, there are better ways to handle this than defines. `constexpr` and `static_assert`s comes to mind, and using standard facilities like [Boost.Predef](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/predef/doc/html/index.html) seem like a better idea than manually defining these things.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to do what you want (nothing can be guaranteed however) if you change your logic.

The C preprocessor has no idea which macro names an OS and which names somwthing else. There is no way to catch a macro that you think names some OS other than the three you can handle. Instead of many possible macro names, use one macro with many possible values. Now when you see a value you cannot handle, you may be able to do something.

```
 #define WINDOWS 1002437 // a random magic number
 #define UNIX 2753321
 ...

 #define OS UNIX

 ...

 #if OS == WINDOWS
   ...
 #elseif OS == UNIX
   ...
 #elseif ...
  ...
 #else // here comes the trick
    #define OS 99997321
    #error "Bad OS"
 #endif
```

If a macro is defined, many compilers will warn you about its redefinition, and say exactly where the first definition may be found. This is not guaranteed however.

Of course if OS is never defined, there is no even a theoretical possibility to pinpoint the place where it is *not* defined. If you know where it *should be* defined, you can use `__LINE__` and `__FILE__` directives to direct the compiler to that place:

```
    #line 11
    #error "OS should be defined here"
```

In real software however such macros are normally defined by the compiler command line, and controlled by your makefile or equivalent.

```
   CPPFLAGS += "-DOS=$(OS_ID)"
```

so there's no place in the source code that can be blamed for an error.